# Seeking browser viewer for las data?

Tags: lidar, software-recommendations, las, web

I am currently preparing lots of las files for analysis and am wondering about the easiest way to share the results on my intranet.

Are there any cool web application for displaying and navigating within las point clouds?

Answer (score 2):

One web app I know of is called [Potree](http://potree.org/) and it's open source.

It was successfully used in a project called Mapping the Via Appia ([link](http://mappingtheviaappia.nl/)), with a point cloud from terrestrial laser scanning. I'm not aware of the technicalities of implementing Potree but I'm pretty sure you'll be able to find the relevant info online.